# React 0.14.8 doesn't trigger Router's createElement

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I'm trying to bump React from 0.13.3 to 0.14.8, but my old setup doesn't work anymore. I've solved all issues very easily, but now I'm stuck and I can't find any hint in the upgrad guide(s).

Here is my setup:

```
const createElement = (Component, props) => <Component {...props} {...store.getState()}/>
const routes = <Router createElement{createElement} history={browserHistory}><Route>...</Route></Router>;
store.subscribe(() => ReactDOM.render(routes, containerElement));
```

So basically, everytime the `store` changes, `ReactDOM.render` is called and `routes` is rendered. `routes` should call `createElement` on render and did just that in `0.13`, but not anymore in `0.14`. Only when the route/url changes, the UI is updated with the latest data.

Any idea where the problem is coming from (React, ReactRouter, Redux) and how to debug/fix are most welcome!

Comment: what version of React Router are you using?

Comment: v2.0.1 (latest as of writing)

Comment: If the url is not changing, then Router is likely just using the existing components instead of making new ones.  Any reason you don't use react-redux to trigger your components to update when the store changes?

Comment: If I update everything (Redux & React Router) the problem does not occur. Only when I update React(DOM) to 0.14.8, createElement is not called anymore. I started with updating the libs and keeping the setup, than I tried react-redux-router which I did not get to work. Initially I didn't use `react-redux`, because I first need to understand, before I abstract.